# Getting JSON null from with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I wrote two code both are same

1. Using NSURLConnection and
2. Using AFNetworking.

My `NSURLConnection` code works fine but `AFNetworking` code don’t. Problem is I am getting JSON response from my `NSURLConnection` code but I am not getting `JSON` response from `AFNetworking` code but I am getting response code as 200. . I have tried all possible combination but still no luck. I dont know what is the problem. I wnat to use `AFNetworking` going forward so please someone help me. Thank you, -- Amit

NSURLConnection:

```
- (IBAction)connectHandler:(UIButton *)sender {

//This is where we attempt to connect to the URL represented by self.labelHostURL
//along with exception handling
NSString *request_type = @"STARTUP";    
NSString *request_data = @"{\"lstCacheRefDt\":\"10/10/2010\",\"langCd\":\"en_US\",\"timeZn\":\"America/Chicago\",\"brndId\":\"WM\",\"prgmId\":\"WM0012\"}";
NSLog(@"Request: %@", request_data);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ self.labelHostURL text ]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
//NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[request_data UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString* request_body = [NSString
                          stringWithFormat:@"request_type=%@&request_data=%@",
                          [request_type stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                          [request_data stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:[request_body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];    }
```

AFNetworking:

```
- (void) getHomeData {

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://localhost:8443/MNMMLMockService/mAccountsWeb/services/mnapp/rpc"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSDictionary *homePostParams1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"10/10/2010", @"lstCacheRefDt",
                                @"en_US", @"langCd",
                                @"America/Chicago", @"timeZn",
                                @"WM", @"brndId",
                                @"WM0012", @"prgmId", nil];

NSDictionary *homePostParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"STARTUP", @"request_type", homePostParams1,@"request_data", nil];

NSLog(@"Dic: %@", homePostParams);

NSMutableURLRequest *homeRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"" parameters:homePostParams];
[homeRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[homeRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:homeRequest
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                         NSLog(@"JSON %@", JSON);
                                         NSLog(@"operation StatusCode: %d", [response statusCode]);
                                     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                         NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];
[operation start]; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use AFNetworking library but you seem to be missing some steps that I do.  I usually subclass AFHTTPClient. Whether you subclass or not, make sure to call AFHTTPClient's registerHTTPOperationClass method.

For example in my AFHTTPClient subclass during the init process, I do (where self is AFHTTPClient instance) :

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

This will set the appropriate accept headers for you.

For operations (all expect json responses), I do something like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *httpOperation = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseJSONObject) { // some logic}
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { // some logic }];
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you want to send url form encoded data instead of JSON to the server, but expect JSON back. Don't set the header fields. Remove this:

```
[homeRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[homeRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

If you want to set that (though you shouldn't have to) you do it with `AFHTTPClient`. For example:

```
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

Furthermore, you do know that `AFNetworking` encodes/decodes JSON for you, right? You pass it an object and it will automatically encode it as JSON and likewise will automatically take JSON received and decode it to an objective-c object. So you will never receive plain JSON from `AFNetworking` library, you will receive the corresponding object.

**Edit**

I see your problem now. You are expecting `AFNetworking` to url form encode half of the parameters, but also JSON encode the other part. With `AFNetworking` you must either encode the entire parameter object as one thing or the other. I suggest you change to 100% JSON by keeping the homePostParams you created and encoding it with JSON, then rewriting the server to expect all JSON.

If you must have it split like that, you can't rely on `AFNetworking` to do the encoding/decoding for you. You must do what you did with the `NSURLConnection`:

```
NSString *request_data = @"{\"lstCacheRefDt\":\"10/10/2010\",\"langCd\":\"en_US\",\"timeZn\":\"America/Chicago\",\"brndId\":\"WM\",\"prgmId\":\"WM0012\"}";
NSDictionary *homePostParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"STARTUP", @"request_type", request_data,@"request_data", nil];
```

Kind of defeats the purpose of `AFNetworking` though. Would be much better if the server just expected to receive JSON and not url form encoding

Comment: Thank you for the response but no luck.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare check out my edit. Are you expecting raw JSON, but getting an object?

Comment: @AmitVyawahare I see now why you are doing form encoding, may I suggest that instead of form encoding you do 100% JSON. The problem in lies that AFNetworking will either encode the entire homePostParams as JSON or none. You are expecting it to be half form encoded and half JSON encoded. So if you want the server to receive any JSON either it has to be 100% JSON or you have to use a very similar encoding scheme as above, but that pretty much defeats the purpose of `AFNetworking`

Comment: I am getting error with this edit. as Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)},

Comment: It is possible that `AFJSONRequestOperation` requires one of those content-types. Or you can try setting the content-type to be url form encoded. With something like `[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];`. It might work, but it makes sense that if you are using `AFJSONRequestOperation` you are pretty much expecting to be sending and receiving JSON.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare I would suggest just moving to sending and receiving 100% JSON. It just makes more sense. So if you have any control over the server application, just do the simple rewrite to expect all JSON. It will make life easier in a multitude of ways.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare You're getting that error because `AFJSONRequestOperation` is expecting the `Content-Type` of the response to be some form of JSON. Either set the correct content-type (if you can change the server), or have the JSON operation class register whatever content type you're receiving as acceptable.